# JS Classlist remove

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having problem with removing a class from an element. I've tried it many ways, but still it won't work. What could the problem be?
Thanks!

```js
function boxClick(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList.add("valami");
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute("id", "currentBox");
}

function closeBox() {
  var openedBox = document.getElementsByClassName("valami");
  var curBox = document.getElementById("currentBox");
  curBox.classList.remove("valami");
}

var gridBoxok = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-box-content");
for (var i = 0; i < gridBoxok.length; i++) {
  gridBoxok[i].addEventListener('click', boxClick, false);
}

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close-container");
for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].addEventListener('click', closeBox, false);
}
```

```css
.valami {
  outline: solid yellow 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="grid-box-content">
      <div class="close-container">
        fdfadsf
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have any element with the id 'currentBox' in the markup you posted.

Comment: @Evan Yes, but the first function gives the ID curBox to the div

Comment: i believe whats happening is you are calling boxClick to add a listener to the grid-box-content then you add another listener over the grid-box-content which means that closebox will get called first

Comment: so basically you made event listener for the grid-box then you made a new listener which overlapped the old one which means we can't click that first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to stop event bubbling in close event handler, otherwise after `closeBox` (removes class) event keeps propagating up the DOM tree and when it reaches `.grid-box-content` it causes `boxClick` (add class) execute again.

Try this:

```
function closeBox(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // <--- add this line
  var openedBox = document.getElementsByClassName("valami");
  var curBox = document.getElementById("currentBox")
  curBox.classList.remove("valami");
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cy5ukzcg/

Comment: you sure it's not just what i claimed in comments? this doesnt fix it when i try it... it's reading a null value doesnt that imply it doesnt find anything

Comment: @L_Church Your understanding is correct. However in order to properly test it you need to click `grid-box-content` and not `close-container`. The HTML doesn't show it, but I assume there are some styles to make it possible to click content without clicking close button. Check the demo i created where I used paddings to create content clickable area and separate it from close container.

Comment: yeah i saw your demo highlighted that my b :D

Comment: nice, forgot about the stopPropagation (that';s why I thought the close binding was wrong)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are binding your close is incorrect, I would do it like below.  Also `.add` and `.remove` [don't work in certain browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) so I changed the way that the class was added and removed:

```js
function boxClick(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList += " valami";
  e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('click', boxClick); // remove box click
  e.currentTarget.addEventListener('click', closeBox);  // bind close click
}

function closeBox(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList = e.currentTarget.className.replace(" valami", "");
  e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('click', closeBox); // remove close click
  e.currentTarget.addEventListener('click', boxClick);  // bind box click
}


var gridBoxok = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-box-content");
for (var i = 0; i < gridBoxok.length; i++) {
  gridBoxok[i].addEventListener('click', boxClick);
}
```

```css
.valami {
  outline: solid yellow 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="grid-box-content">
      <div class="close-container">
        fdfadsf
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit, sorry, didn't realise the close binding was on a different element within the parent. So close binding was correct, but you needed to stop propagation of click like in dfsq's answer.  Will leave this though as an alternate way of updating class list (in case you need to support ie)